# looking for search engine service for drupal that wont include my data to public index

Tags: search, drupal, google-custom-search, yahoo-boss-api

i tried drupal core search and its kinda disappointing, i used many moudles to improve it but its not good enough, and i dont wana install apachesolr , is there a search engine api / service (even that costs some 10-200$) that can index my site better and wont expose the data in drupal to the engine public search like google do?

Comment: Not that I know of, for Drupal.  Most people use SOLR, but you've asked not to go that route.

Comment: People will be more willing to help you if you give some feedback (upvotes or mark as accepted) on some of the answers you've received for your other questions.  Surely at least one of them was helpful enough to deserve an upvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acquia offers [hosted Solr Search](http://acquia.com/products-services/acquia-search), which wouldn't require you to "install" Apache Solr. They take care of installing and hosting it on their servers. You'd just need to install and enable the associated modules.